# More professional word for "day to day task"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a more professional term or phrase to describe “day to day task” or a task that is very common for a particular role of work.

Comment: What do you find "unprofessional" about your current selection? I cannot see it.

Comment: "Daily" or "Regular" task is what we use at my job.

Comment: The Latin term for "day-to-day" or "everyday" in this usage is _quotidian_. Being Latin, it falutes higher.

Answer (score 5):

How about ***routine*** tasks?

> [Routine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/routine): commonplace tasks, chores, or duties as must be done regularly or at specified intervals; typical or everyday activity:

Answer (score 1):

From [*Thesaurus.com*](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/day-to-day) (scroll down a little):

> *day-to-day* [ dey-tuh-dey ]
> Main Entry: daily
> Part of Speech: adjective
> Definition: occurring every day; during the day
>
> *Synonyms*: circadian, common, commonplace, constantly, cyclic, day after day, day by day, day-to-day, diurnal, everyday, from day to day, often, once a day, once daily, ordinary, per diem, periodic, quotidian, regular, regularly, routine

Of the synonyms listed above,
*circadian, diurnal* and *quotidian*
are more formal, being Latinate; these are less likely to be understood in casual speech or non-academic writing.

Answer (score 0):

### Business as usual, often abbreviated as BAU.

Quoting from [an article about the term on the job site indeed.com](https://www.indeed.com/hire/c/info/business-as-usual):

> Business as usual refers broadly to any situation where everything is proceeding as normal and as expected. In a business context, a BAU process is any element of day-to-day operations that are largely the same day after day.