# list of tasks that are to be done every month/period

Tags: single-word-requests

What can be a single word for a list of tasks that are to be done every month/period?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236805/14666

Answer (score 1):

"Recurrent Tasks," "Regular Tasks," or "Periodic Tasks."

**[Recurring tasks](https://www.projectplan365.com/training/lesson-2-add-recurring-tasks/)**

> Recurring tasks might come handy if you have in your project a task that will happen every couple of days or every month. However if you have a repeating task that isn't on a regular schedule, you need to create a separate task for each occurrence. Therefore, if a task repeats at set intervals, enter it as a recurring task. If it does not repeat at set intervals, enter it as a regular task every time that it occurs. For example, attending a monthly project debriefing or generating a quarterly project report is considered a recurring task.

Answer (score 1):

**Chore** is probably not quite right, but it might be just the thing for your particular application.

Comment: Actually, [*chore*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chore) is exactly the right single word: "regular or daily light work" and "a routine task or job." I would edit your answer to include the full Merriam-Webster definition, which shows that the single word *does* mean a recurring task.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> isochronous

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/isochronal):

> performed in equal intervals of time.

Answer (score 0):

If "**routine**" hasn't been mentioned here, it should be. There can also be a customary "**schedule**" (of tasks) that people follow without writing them down (shopping, laundry, workouts etc. - but can be done religiously). Either of these lists can be repeated in any timeframe - daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, semi-annually....pretty much known as a personal "**calendar**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/routine

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/schedule

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/calendar